# Redirect to a component which is not inside of route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Here is my project router setup. After a successful user login. The user went into dashboard component. I use a redirect for this purpose and it works fine(As both the component are at the same level I guess).

Primary Router

```
<Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                </Switch>
</Router>
```

Secondary Route

```
 <Router>
               <Header />
               <div className="col-md-12">
                   <div className="row">
                   <Sidebar />
                   <div className="offset-md-2 col-md-10 col-sm-10 bg-gray" style={padding}>
                   <Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Homepage} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/check-in" component={CheckIn} />
                   </Switch>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </Router>
```

Now I want to redirect from my checking component to the login component in the very beginning. I use a redirect for this task. But it shows me a blank page. Probably it didn't load any component.

Comment: I think you are looking for relative paths..

Comment: You could do <Redirect to="../dashboard" /> If this doesn't work would you mind putting something in code sandbox and share a link?

Comment: Why do you have two Router instances